# Extjs, filtering grid dynamically

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, filtering, extjs4.1

I'm developping with extjs4.
I have two grids as shown in the image, I want when I click on the line of `Grid Panel 1` that contanis `Number 1`, the `Grid Panel 2` will show only lines that contains `Number 1`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is pretty much straightforward; subscribe to the select event of the first grid and within that handler filter the store of the second grid. That's it.

```
grid1.on('select', function(grid,record) { 
   grid2.store.clearFilter(true); // see http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-clearFilter
   grid2.store.filter('Number', record.get('Number');
},this);
```

Comment: that's the solution, but I still have a problem, when I click on the line of `Grid Panel 1` that contanis `Number 1`, the `Grid Panel 2` will be filtered, and then when I click on the line of `Grid Panel 1` that contanis `Number 3`, `Grid Panel 2` will not show what I want because it contain just `Number 1`!

Comment: @Aminesrine See my edit. Now it should again do what you want.

Comment: Thanks @sra :)  
I have another question please, I want when the `Grid Panel 1` is rendered, it won't show lines that contain `Number 1`. It will show all but `Number 1`.

Comment: @Aminesrine I don't get it... can you please elaborate?

Comment: `Grid Panel 1` contains many Number,0,1,2,3,4.. I want to remove lines that contain Number 0.

Comment: @Aminesrine Well if I understand you right then you could apply a filter too. Sort of `grid1.store.filterBy(function(record) { return record.get('Number') > 0 });` This should only show numbers greater then 0